# shell/bash script to install cpan modules automatically

Tags: bash, shell, perl, cpan

I want a shell script that will find the directory where perl is installed in local system, open that perl, and install all the CPAN modules automatically.

Answer (score 4):

I think [cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/pod/App%3a%3acpanminus) is what you are looking for.

You can install modules like this:

`cpanm Dancer Dancer::Plugin::Database (etc. etc.)`

It will install these modules with all dependencies.

Comment: cpanm is command line application to manage modules and also it is module for managing from script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing a module and want all of it's dependencies, just tell the `cpan` command the module you want and it takes care of the rest.

```
% cpan Some::Module
```

The utilities that comes with `perl` already know where `perl` is because they adjust their shebang line to be the `perl` that installed them. They'll get all the settings from that `perl` when it starts.

If you want to use some other `perl`, run `cpan` with that `perl`. Now all the settings come from `/my/other/perl`.

```
% /my/other/perl `which cpan` Some::Module
```

Additionally, you can dump the `cpan` settings with `-J`, fiddle with them, and load them for a single run of `cpan`:

```
% cpan -J > settings.dump
...adjust settings...
% cpan -j settings.dump
```